# How to perform load testing for website using JMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I want to create a script in JMeter that simulates e.g. 100 users accessing our site over a period of 3-4 minutes.

We need to test whether our application can allow 25.000 users/day - that is 1.100 per hour.

For that i have made this Jmeter test:

[image]
[image]

and here is the result

[image]

and here is the graph

[image]

I want to know what this result is exactly telling us, if my test pass or fails, if yahoo.com (for which we have run this test for our example) can allow 25.000 users/day and if i am inputting my criteria / requirements correctly?

Thanks

Comment: do you realize that accessing a site involves numerous HTTP requests and you're just testing the initial one? you will need to record an HTTP request sequence (with JMeter - google how to) and test against it

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 45):

**1.** I would advise to use better some custom samplers from [jmeter-plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) instead:

- [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/): more flexible implementation of Thread Group allows to setup your load-testing scenario *exactly* how you want;
- [Response Times Over Time](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime) / [Response Times vs Threads](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesVsThreads) / [Active Threads Over Time](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime) listeners: more demonstrative graphs as JMeter's default ones.

**2.** In addition to the @Qwe comment above: test not the single HTTP request but user's transactions: each test-thread should simulate a kind of real-user browsing activity: login (if any), navigating through the site, search, accessing/editing personal settings, logout, etc.
To emulate real-user add also "think-time" timer between transaction steps.

**3.** Control responses, at least the following:

- *response code* of each user's request (@ [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion));
- *duration* - to verify [non-functional requirements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) for critical transactions (@ [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion)).

**4.** Look into corresponding JMeter documentation:

- [My boss wants me to load test our web app!](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/boss.html)
- [JMeter Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/)

**5.** Some step-by-step guidelines about Jmeter setup and usage for load-testing you can find here:

- [Load Testing your Applications with Apache JMeter](http://web.archive.org/web/20120302160128/http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/JMeter/)
- [Using JMeter](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/01/15/jmeter.html)
- [Effective load testing with Apache JMeter](http://www.davegardner.me.uk/blog/2010/09/23/effective-load-testing-with-apache-jmeter/)
- Load Testing with JMeter: [part 1](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/2011/sep/21/load-testing-jmeter-part-1-getting-started/), [part 2](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/2011/oct/12/load-testing-jmeter-part-2-headless-testing-and-je/), [part 3](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/2012/sep/19/load-testing-jmeter-part-3-replaying-apache-logs/)
- [A Simple Load Test with JMeter](https://www.urbaninsight.com/2011/07/18/simple-load-test-with-jmeter)
- [Load Testing with Apache JMeter](http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/17950)

  [Performance testing with JMeter](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2008/10/performance_testing_with_jmete/)
- [Your First JMeter Test](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=269)
- Some thoughts on stress testing web applications with JMeter: [part 1](http://nico.vahlas.eu/2010/03/17/some-thoughts-on-stress-testing-web-applications-with-jmeter-part-1/), [part 2](http://nico.vahlas.eu/2010/03/30/some-thoughts-on-stress-testing-web-applications-with-jmeter-part-2/).

---

**UPD.**
Please find, use and feel free to extend this [Awesome JMeter](https://github.com/aliesbelik/awesome-jmeter) collection continued on github.

Comment: [Load Testing your Applications with Apache JMeter](http://web.archive.org/web/20120302160128/http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/JMeter/) via archive.org

Comment: Great answer, thanks, it was quite useful also for me.

Comment: @AliaksandrBelik, How long have you been doing loadrunner?

Comment: @Pacerier, if you mean HP LoadRunner tool so I'm not a big fan of it. If you mean something different - please clarify your question.

Comment: @AliaksandrBelik, Ops the edit didn't get through. I meant: How long have you been using JMeter / Loadrunner / Selenium (/ etc)?